# Detect outgoing calls, issue with a real device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I have a strange problem. To detect outgoing calls I have registered a broadcast receiver for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`. When the state becomes OFFHOOK, then a conversation is started. It seems working on emulator: the debugger in fact reaches some code while it doesn't work on real device (Acer Liquid). Is it possible?
Which is a way to detect outgoing calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if it works on the emulator, I would expect it to work on the device. You might registering a `PhoneStateListener` with the `TelephonyManager` via `listen()` and see if it gets you better results.

If you think of it, comment on this answer with the results of your testing.

Comment: The problem was not to use static receiver or dynamic receiver. The problem was related to the android lifecycle. It should work in both ways.