# Detecting outgoing call and call hangup event in android

Tags: android, state, phone-call

I have a requirement wherein I want to detect two kind of events related to Calls in Android

1. Whenever an outgoing call is made, my application should get to know this along with the called number
2. When the call is hanged up(due to success/failure), my application should get to know this along with the reason of hangup

Is this possible in Android?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should create a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class CallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                // Phone number 
                String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                // Ringing state
                // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

            // This code will execute when the call is answered or disconnected
        }

    }
}
```

You should register you application to listen to these intents in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReciever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code

Is there a way for capturing the Outgoing call as well similar to the way Incoming call is captured?

Comment: @user669231 Yes, you should change the check in the if-state. You can see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668445/detect-outgoing-calls-and-problem-with-a-real-device

Comment: Works like a charm. Additionally you have to declare the following permission in the manifest.xml file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

otherwise this won't work.

See API of TelephonyManager class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: The code is executing twice that is written in `else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) { }` block. In this block I am getting details of outgoing calls. Please suggest why is this happening ??

Comment: the same problem described in the above comment is happened to me. Somebody help us to solve the problem of getting the same phonestate in multiple times.

Comment: but still not able to detect that call is received by recipient.

Answer (score 9):

There is a simpler solution using only TelephonyManager and 
PhoneStateListener.You don´t even have to register a BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            //Hangup
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                break;
            //Outgoing
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                break;
            //Incoming
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And to register it:

```
public static void registerListener(Context context) {
    ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(new MyPhoneStateListener(),
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

Comment: I used this one but the problem is onCallStateChanged callback is not triggering.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a receiver for the following intent actions:

1. Outgoing call - [ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)
2. Call hangup - [ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)

Comment: Can you give me a example for that, My need for outgoing call

Comment: The above described solution worked perfectly for me.But the receiver is receiving the same state for multiple times. How can we solve this?. Is there anyway to detect the id of receiving intent or some other ways?