# How can I obtain the result of an outgoing call

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'd like to know the result of an outgoing call (i.e. whether or not the phone on the other end answered or no one ever picked up). I'm trying to make a list of phone numbers that do answer when called and ones that don't answer when called.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668445/detect-outgoing-calls-and-problem-with-a-real-device) and go through this documentations [(1)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL),[(2)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED).
The article mentioned below will also help you to start with your stuff.
[detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/)

All the best.

Comment: thak you, but i want to know exactly how we come to know the call is pickdup or not. if not pickup the call then how to terminate the call. because i need go for ohter number to make call.

Comment: Just go through this article. It will give you some tips to proceed. http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

Comment: please do clarify,in PhoneStateListener class we have onCallStateChanged() and get the staus is ringing,offhook,idle. is three states for outgoing(when i diled and call is going) number or incoming number(means when outgoing call is going and any incoming call is arrived in my phone). what i actually want is i made a call with startActivity(callintent); then i want to get the status of outgoing call ie..... whether its ringing/waiting/unavailable.

Comment: I dont know whether you can do all these things but see `off_hook` will give you **At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.** and ringing will give the **A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting. In the latter case, another call is already active.** Make use of this.

Comment: k.i will try. and i want to end the outgoing call.how? by using broadcastreceiver->onreceive()->this.abortBroadCact(). is it correct?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/android-how-to-hang-up-outgoing-call. You can end the call based on the suggestions given here.

Comment: how do we wait the control over a time (eq:30sec/20sec). that is in my module i have check the status of outgoing call if ringing ... set the time to wait for some timeand finish/trminate call by me. do u have idea?